# Looking for a raster calculator C# class

Tags: raster-calculator, dotspatial

I am developing an application using C# and dotspatial. I need to performs raster calculation a lot..I need a library which helps me to do it..Do you know any library for this purpose?
The library must consider boundary of input rasters and also input bands and pixel sizes..

I only need some operations such as  +,-,* and /